# How to remove the CPU info from vmstat command using python

Tags: python

The vmstat command has the following output, I am trying to remove the cpu part and print in python
vmstat

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0  30468  23468  36496 837876    0    0   143   179   57  105  2  1 97  1
```

using the following python code i am losing spaces, how do i properly format
so that output looks exactly like the above with the cpu part removed

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('vmstat', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
line1 = p.stdout.readlines()
line2 = ' '.join(line1[0].split()[:-1])
line3 = ' '.join(line1[1].split()[:-5])
line4 = ' '.join(line1[2].split()[:-5])
print line2
print line3
print line4

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system--
r b swpd free buff cache si so bi bo in
0 0 30468 20608 36548 837880 0 0 143 179 57
```

Comment: Please check my answer. If it solves your problem, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Lets first find the position of CPU header and then strip the remaining charecters. I have made it generic, so that calling `vmstat_without_field` with a field name will remove it from the output.

```
import subprocess
import re

def vmstat_without_field(field = 'cpu'):
    lines = subprocess.Popen('vmstat', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).stdout.readlines()
    match_obj = re.search('\s-+%s-+' % field, lines[0])
    start = match_obj.start()
    end = match_obj.end()

    for line in lines:
        line = line[:start] + line[end:]
        line = line[:-1] if line[-1] == '\n' else line
        print(line)

vmstat_without_field()
```